# Convert List<List<String>> to a list<String> java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, stream

I've `ArrayList<List<String>>` which contains data. e.g:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

I tried to convert it into `List<String>` but it becomes

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Code:

```
List<String> f = 
            ch.stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(f);
```

How can I convert it into the following output so could get a index by `list.get(index)`

```
List<String> list = [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3];
```

Comment: I don't think `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` is a valid `List<List<String>>`.  Nor, for that matter, is `[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]` a `List<String>`.

Comment: Actually it's a csv data and each row is stored as list inside another list

Comment: @john So you want data of each row? give the index and get a list of data. what is your main goal?

Comment: Actually I have the data of each row. I just want to extract the list<string> out of Arraylist<list<String>> so I could write it into csv file. I used the above code but it converting all rows to one list<string>

Comment: @john I think you didn't get why it's Arraylist<list<String>>. You can change or delete data in this form too. But if you want to extract lists, the only thing you get is a single list.  List<String> list = [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]; this is not even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after the following?

```
    List<List<String>> ch = List.of(List.of("1", "2", "3"), List.of("1", "2", "3"), List.of("1", "2", "3"));
    
    System.out.println(ch);
    
    List<String> f = ch.stream()
            .map(List::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.println(f);
```

In the output the two lists look the same:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

But we can see from the code that the former is a list of lists, the latter just a list of strings.